# React: change button text while doing work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my [React](https://reactjs.org) application, I would like a button that normally says `Save`, changes its text to `Saving...` when clicked and changes it back to `Save` once saving is complete.

This is my first attempt:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class SaveButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isSaving : false };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick() {
    // DOES NOT WORK
    this.setState({ isSaving : true });
    this.props.onClick();
    this.setState({ isSaving : false });
  }

  render() {
    const { isWorking } = this.state;
    return (
      <Button bsStyle="primary"
              onClick={isWorking ? null : this.onClick}>
        {isWorking ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'}
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

export default SaveButton;
```

This doesn't work because both [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and `this.props.onClick()` (passed in by the parent component) are executed asynchronously, so the calls return immediately and the change to `state` is probably lost in React optimization (and would probably be visible only for a few milliseconds anuway...).

I read up on [component state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and decided to [lift up state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to where it belongs, the parent component, the form whose changes the button saves (which in my app rather is a distant ancestor than a parent). So I removed `isSaving` from `SaveButton`, replaced

```
const { isWorking } = this.state;
```

by

```
const { isWorking } = this.props.isWorking;
```

and tried to set the state in the form parent component. However, this might be architecturally cleaner, but essentially only moved my problem elsewhere:

The actual saving functionality is done at a totally different location in the application. In order to trigger it, I pass `onClick` event handlers down the component tree as props; the call chain back up that tree upon a click on the button works. But how do I notify about completion of the action in the opposite direction, i.e. down the tree ?

**My question:** How do I notify the form component that maintains state that saving is complete ?

The form's parent component (which knows about save being complete) could use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), but there isn't only one of those forms, but a whole array.

Do I have to set up a list of refs, one for each form ?
Or would this be a case where [forwarding refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) is appropriate ?

Thank you very much for your consideration! :-)

Comment: You usually don't want to use a ref. Instead, why not have the parent component also pass down a handle to an `onSaveSuccess()` function that the children can call as needed?

Comment: Can you just await the onClick request? Assuming the onClick is a post request to some server, you `await` the `onClick()` so that `async onClick()` never reaches the `this.setState({ isSaving : false });` until the request is done.

Answer (score 1):

> This doesn't work because both setState and this.props.onClick()
>   (passed in by the parent component) are executed asynchronously, so
>   the calls return immediately and the change to state is probably lost
>   in React optimization

`setState` can [take a callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to let you know once state has been updated, so you can have:

```
onClick() {
    this.setState({ isSaving : true }, () => {
       this.props.onClick();
       this.setState({ isSaving : false });
    }); 
}
```

If `this.props.onClick()` is also async, turn it into a promise:

```
onClick() {
    this.setState({ isSaving : true }, () => {
       this.props.onClick().then(() => {
         this.setState({ isSaving : false });
       });
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you see ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

---

parent component's onClick function

```
onClick(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  //example code 
    for(let i=0;i<100000;i++){
      //or api call
    }
    resolve();
  })
}
```

SaveButton component's onClick funtion

```
onClick(){
  this.setState({ isSaving : true });
  this.props.onClick().then(function(){
    this.setState({ isSaving : false });
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code that works :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class SaveButton extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isSaving: false
        };
        this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleOnClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                isSaving: !prevState.isSaving
            }
        });
        console.log("Clicked!",this.state.isSaving);
        this.handleSave();
    }
    handleSave() {
        // Do what ever and if true => set isSaving = false
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.setState(prevState=>{
                return {
                    isSaving: !prevState.isSaving
                }
            })
        },5000)
    }

    render() {
        const  isWorking  = this.state.isSaving;
        return (
            <Button
                    bsStyle="primary"
                    onClick={this.handleOnClick}
            >
                    {isWorking ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'}
            </Button>

        );
    }
}

export default SaveButton;
```

You need to change `const isWorking` instead of `const {isWorking}` and you need to handle save function in some manner.
In this example I used timeout of 5 second to simulate saving.